# Duplicate dlopen's RTLD_DEEPBIND behavior with linker flag

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, dlopen

Is there a linker flag that would duplicate the behavior of `RTLD_DEEPBIND` on a specified library?

I am trying to avoid having to `dlopen` my library and call `dlsym` for every function just to get the `RTLD_DEEPBIND` behavior. Even if there's a way to `dlopen` and then have the symbols automatically resolved without `dlsym` that would be an acceptable solution.

dlopen ref: http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a linker flag that would duplicate the behavior of RTLD_DEEPBIND on a specified library?

Yes: `-Bsymbolic`.

Note: both `-Bsymbolic` and `RTLD_DEEPBIND` can have hard to debug [side effects](https://web.archive.org/web/20150531091913/https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-bsymbolic-can-cause-dangerous-side-effects/).

Comment: Archived version of that side effects link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150531091913/https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-bsymbolic-can-cause-dangerous-side-effects/